# Is there a verbose mode for trajectory optimization?

Tags: drake

When we are calling functions like [`DirectCollocation`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1trajectory__optimization_1_1_direct_collocation.html), is there a way to see some progress in the middle (verbose mode)? I am not sure how helpful it is to check formulation errors. But just wondering :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to monitor the progress

1. You could add a visual call back function with [`prog.AddVisualizationCallback`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program.html#a67626d45d9a119d01e1c046ad89ee556). If this callback function visualizes the trajectory, then you can monitor the visualization in every iteration of the optimizer.
2. If you use Snopt solver, then you could ask the solver to print out statistics on each iteration. The pseudo-code looks like this

   ```cpp
   std::string print_file_name="foo.txt";
   prog.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver::id(), "Print file", print_file_name);
   SnoptSolver solver;
   const auto result = solver.Solve(prog, initial_guess);
   ```

   Then Snopt will print its statistics in each iteration to foo.txt.

Comment: BTW Here's Hongkai's recently merged tutorials for `AddVisualizationCallback`:
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/nightly-release/tutorials/mathematical_program.ipynb#Add-callback